# Cannot print out the right sum

Tags: java, loops

I have assigned a letter grade to each student based on his/her grade.  And I want to count the total number of students for each letter grade.  But for some reasons, the result turns total wrong. Can anyone tell me what parts I did wrong? Thank you!

```
String letter ="A";
int letterA=0;
int letterB=0;
int letterC=0;
int letterD=0;
int letterF=0;
int a=0;
int b=0;
int c=0;
int d=0;
int f=0;
for (int row=0;row<100;row++){ //the outer loop, have 100 rows to go through 
   for ( int column=0;column<words.length;column++) { 
       if(words[column].equals(table[row][column])){ // compare two arrays
            count++; }// add the score for each student if he/she is right
   }
     if (count >=18)
         letter=("A");
     if(count>=16 && count<18)
         letter=("B");
     if(count>=14 && count<16)
         letter=("C");
     if(count>=12 && count<14)
         letter=("D");      
     if(count<12)
         letter=("F");    
    System.out.println("Student Grade: "+letter+"\t");   
     count=0; // make sure the count will go back to 0, and run the loop again 

if (letter.equals("A"))
     letterA++;
     a+=letterA;}  
if (letter.equals("B"))
     letterB++;
     b+=letterB;
if (letter.equals("C"))
     letterC++;
     c+=letterC;
if (letter.equals("D"))
     letterD++;
     d+=letterD;
if (letter.equals("F"))
     letterF++;
     f+=letterF;
System.out.print("Question A "+a);
System.out.print("Question B "+b);
System.out.print("Question C "+c);
System.out.print("Question D "+d);
System.out.print("Question F "+f);
 }
```

Comment: You have a brace, "{", in the wrong place after your `letter.equals("A")` check..

Comment: I don't think you need both `letterA` and `a` (and the same for other letter grades).  In fact, you're incrementing `a` by the number of A's every time someone has an A.  As @Buddy said, you have a brace at the end of the line `a+=letterA;}`.  That brace should be right before the `System.out.print` statements.

Comment: Silly mistake. But the result is still incorrect after I move the "} " .  The total student should be 100.. but the end result add up to 5050.. Should I delete something?

Comment: print out `letterA` instead of `a`

Comment: You are correct. Once I change it to LetterA, it is right now!! Thank you. Can you tell me why the number will be so big when I try to print out a?  I am little bit confuse.

Comment: Strog intution with these lines of your code `if (letter.equals("A"))
     letterA++;
     a+=letterA;} ` downvoting..unnecessary

Comment: what do you think the single letter variables are supposed to represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Always use braces, even for single statements:

```
if (letter.equals("A"))
     letterA++;
     a+=letterA;}  
if (letter.equals("B"))
     letterB++;
     b+=letterB;
if (letter.equals("C"))
     letterC++;
     c+=letterC;
if (letter.equals("D"))
     letterD++;
     d+=letterD;
if (letter.equals("F"))
     letterF++;
     f+=letterF;
```

Should always be:

```
if ("A".equals(letter)) { letterA++; }
else if ("B".equals(letter)) { letterB++; }
else if ("C".equals(letter)) { letterC++; }
else if ("D".equals(letter)) { letterD++; }
else if ("F".equals(letter)) { letterF++; }
else { throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Letter " + letter); }
```

> Use single line statements if you want them visually compact, but
>   still use the braces as they guarantee the intent of what is to be
>   done in a given block, they also act as documentation of that intent
>   for people in the future ( people includes you ) to know what is going
>   on.

*I see no valid reason for the single letter variables they are never used and I do not understand why they are there?*

### General Critique:

#### Always use braces:

Leaving out braces means only the **first** statement after the `if` is executed when the `if` matches, the next line(s) are **always** executed.

```
if (letter.equals("A"))
     letterA++;
     a+=letterA;
```

is actually

```
if (letter.equals("A")) { letterA++; }
a+=letterA;
```

Which means that line outside the braces will always get executed no matter what the expression inside the `if` test evaluates to. The indention of the second line is conflating that statement as part of the `if` block and it is not.

> There is absolutely **nothing** to gain by leaving out braces and
>   everything to lose.

#### Neat code is easy to read and maintain and shows you care:

Always format your code consistently and not so densely so you can tell what is going on and what was wrong with the braces missing version.

Look at the best advertising it has plenty of [*white space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_space_(visual_arts)), clean formatted code should have plenty of consistent [*white space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_space_(visual_arts)) as well so that our brains can quickly pattern match and scan for relevant things like matching pairs of braces.

Clean formatted code is just a keystroke away in all IDEs worth using.

Clean code shows you care about what you are doing and makes your question more appealing, which means others will care about their answer just as much.

Clean code earns you respect from your peers that know what they are looking at and sets you apart from those that do not care or know what they are looking at.

> Most Importantly Clean Code is easier to reason about and has less
>   bugs, no subtle bugs and is orders of magnitude easier to maintain.

#### Always cover all the conditions:

Always use `if/else if/else` with mutually exclusive tests.

If all the `if` clauses are mutually exclusive and you match the first one, all the rest are still evaluated for no reason with the `if/if/if/if` structure. `if/else if/else if/else if/else` only evaluates until something matches or nothing matches.

Without `else` you do not cover all possible cases that do not match, which is usually and error that will just occur silently without the `else`.

Do not just cover the [*happy path*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path), cover the exceptional path, but do it in the [least defensive manner possible](http://danielroop.com/blog/2009/10/15/why-defensive-programming-is-rubbish/).

> [Explicit is always better than Implicit!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33225054/177800)

#### Avoid `== null` checks; avoid `null` completely:

Always compare literals to variables with `.equals()` to avoid possible `NullPointerExceptions`.

Avoid using `null` references completely, it is possible in every case, even the cases that it seems like a legitimate reason.

> If [Tony Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare), the inventor of them [thinks it is a mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions)
>   who is to argue.

#### Always **Name** your variables descriptively!

I am not sure what `letterA` is supposed to represent anymore than what `a` is supposed to represent. So no one can tell you if these are correct because no one knows for sure what they represent semantically.

#### No Unnamed Numerical Constants ( [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) ):

```
final int A_GRADE = 18;
final int B_GRADE = 16;
final int C_GRADE = 14;
final int D_GRADE = 12;
```

> Given the way they are used the names arguably could be even better
>   like `MINIMUM_A_GRADE`, but that is opinion based, the lesson is avoid
>   magic numbers.

#### Do range checks in the same direction:

Do range checks in the same direction so that the variable is visually in the middle of the comparison. 
This makes it harder to break the logic later on and is self documenting that it is a range check.

```
if (count >= A_GRADE) { /* omitted */ }
else if (B_GRADE <= count && count < A_GRADE) { /* omitted */ }
else if (C_GRADE <= count && count < B_GRADE) { /* omitted */ }
else if (D_GRADE <= count && count < C_GRADE) { /* omitted */ }
else /* isF */ { /* omitted */ }
```

> Which one is easier to reason about and maintain?

#### Do not hesitate to have many small methods if they make the code more self documenting:

```
private static boolean isA(final int count) { return count >= A_GRADE; }
private static boolean isB(final int count) { return B_GRADE <= count && count < A_GRADE; }
private static boolean isC(final int count) { return C_GRADE <= count && count < B_GRADE; }
private static boolean isD(final int count) { return D_GRADE <= count && count < C_GRADE; }
```

then you will have the following:

```
if (isA(count)) { /* omitted */ }
else if (isB(count)) { /* omitted */ }
else if (isC(count)) { /* omitted */ }
else if (isD(count)) { /* omitted */ }
else /* isF */ { /* omitted */ }
```

> Which one is more obvious and self documenting, thus more
>   maintainable?

#### DRY - [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

Logically `if (count >= A_GRADE) { letter = "A";}` is exactly the same as `if ("A".equals(letter)) { /* do stuff */ }` so this is duplicated logic.

Instead of assigning a `letter` than checking that again, just put the logic in the original check.

```
if (count >= A_GRADE) { /* do stuff */ }
else if (B_GRADE <= count && count < A_GRADE) { /* do stuff */ }
else if (C_GRADE <= count && count < B_GRADE) { /* do stuff */ }
else if (D_GRADE <= count && count < C_GRADE) { /* do stuff */ }
else { /* omitted */ }
```

*I see no valid reason for the single letter variables they are never used and I do not understand why they are there?*

> Duplicate logic means multiple places to have errors and multiple
>   places to edit to fix bugs, save yourself time and effort and follow
>   the `DRY` principle.

#### Move large logic blocks to method calls:

When `do stuff` is more than a few lines, refactor it to a method call.

```
if (count >= A_GRADE) { recordMarkA(); }
else if (B_GRADE <= count && count < A_GRADE) { recordMarkB(); }
else if (C_GRADE <= count && count < B_GRADE) { recordMarkC(); }
else if (D_GRADE <= count && count < C_GRADE) { recordMarkD(); }
else { recordMarkF(); }
```

> More small methods with descriptive names is always better than large
>   monolithic blocks of inline code.

### This question shows substantial effort and a genuine desire to learn:

So I crafted up what I would want a complete solution *( provided the partial/incomplete code )* to look like.

[Q34081279.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q34081279.java)

```
public class Q34081279
{
    final static int A_GRADE = 18;
    final static int B_GRADE = 16;
    final static int C_GRADE = 14;
    final static int D_GRADE = 12;

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String[] words = new String[]{}; /* this is just a placeholer, not provided in question */
        final String[][] table = new String[][]{}; /* this is just a placehoder, not provided in question */

        int markA = 0;
        int markB = 0;
        int markC = 0;
        int markD = 0;
        int markF = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < words.length; column++)
            {
                if (words[column].equals(table[row][column])) { count++; }
            }
            if (count >= A_GRADE) { System.out.format("%d = A", count); }
            else if (B_GRADE <= count && count < A_GRADE) { System.out.format("%d = B", count); }
            else if (C_GRADE <= count && count < B_GRADE) { System.out.format("%d = C", count); }
            else if (D_GRADE <= count && count < C_GRADE) { System.out.format("%d = D", count); }
            else { System.out.format("%d = F", count); }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Question A %d", markA));
        System.out.println(String.format("Question B %d", markB));
        System.out.println(String.format("Question C %d", markC));
        System.out.println(String.format("Question D %d", markD));
        System.out.println(String.format("Question F %d", markF));
    }
}
```

Comment: Get it now! thank you so much!  your explanation is really clear.

Comment: Just did it. Again, Thank you! you explanation and suggestions are really useful, especially for a java beginner like me.

Comment: did your instructor not cover these fundamental things? If not you need to ask them why they are not teaching everything you need to know to succeed?

Comment: It is a quick pace class. I think the instructor wants to cover many things. And she usually just read the PowerPoint and left.  I got lost sometimes.  When I code the assignment, I will look for similar code example in the book and try to imitate the example.  If I cannot figure out, I will try to find solution online. So I do not really know a lot fundamental things, like common rules or which way is better than the other.

Comment: You need to find another instructor, the one have is terrible. You can show here this answer and ask her to include it in the PowerPoint if she is too lazy to take 5 minutes to explain things this simple. You are not getting your monies worth, she is doing all of you a disservice.

Comment: Yes, I will go to her office hour tomorrow. Since I am not sure how to draw the pie chart based on numbers I got in this part. I will definitely suggest her to tell the class some fundamental things like what you told me and help us to understand Java better.

Comment: Just to be clear, all these things are not specific to Java and are just basic good coding practices regardless of language. I think they should be taught before you are taught to write a line of code. Kind of like firearms safety training comes **before** you hand someone a weapon, not after!

Comment: Ok.  So those thing will be similar for all other coding language. I remember the first class is the history of Java and we start to learn   public static void main(String[] args){    and System.out.print.   I will suggest the professor add those to the PowerPoint for next semester 's students.  This is the end semester for me.

Comment: these types of things is what a [10X developer](http://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2013/09/29/the-10x-developer-is-not-myth/) does. And no they are not a myth, they are rare, but they exist, luckily I work with a couple right now.

Comment: 10X developer, this is my first time hear that word. The article is awesome.  For a beginner like me, 10X developer seems so cool and far away.  Is that a great but super competitive experience to work with them?

Comment: the sooner you learn and apply [these types of things](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/05/the-final-word-on-final/), the sooner you get there. The more valuable you will be and the more money you should be able to demand. Good Luck, but it does not sound like you need it, you are on the right track.

Comment: Thank you! I am extremely happy to meet you today. So many valuable suggestions and inspirations. Good night.

Answer (score 0):

@Buddy is on the right rack but it's more than that. All of the `if` statements with more than one line need to have braces.

Otherwise only the first line is read by the compiler. According to Oracle:

> Deciding when to omit the braces is a matter of personal taste. Omitting them can make the code more brittle. If a second statement is later added to the "then" clause, a common mistake would be forgetting to add the newly required braces. The compiler cannot catch this sort of error; you'll just get the wrong results.

eg:

```
if (letter.equals("A")) {
  letterA++;
  a+=letterA;
}  
if (letter.equals("B")) {
  letterB++;
  b+=letterB;
}
```